# Time trigger on Google Scheet and Survey Monkey API addon

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, surveymonkey, google-apps-script-addon

I'm during my university project and I'm using SurveyMonkey to gather data for my team usage.

To easily read and maintain with the data, I use API Connector Add-On in Google Scheet to download latest responses from Survey Monkey, especially when due to my Uni policy I am the only person who can have access to Survey Monkey in my team.

The problem is that we need to make the data refresh every 5 minutes, as due to the project characteristics the amount of rapidly sent responses have to be monitored by us during 4h window every day and every 5 minutes.

The API Connector allows me to re-run request for data automatically, but only for every 1 hour, which is not sufficient for me and my team. I've tried to use Google Apps Script from [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50382884/time-trigger-on-google-sheet-add-on), but unfortunately I can't modify to make it work due to my lack of knowledge.

```
 function onInstall() {
  onOpen(); 
}
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Schedule')
  .addItem('Start Schedule', 'menuItem3')
  .addToUi();
}

function menuItem3() {
  createTrigger();
}

function createTrigger()
{
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('startProcess')
    .timeBased()
    .everyDays(1)
    .create(); 
}


function startProcess(){
// Add your processing logic here. e.g. send notifications.
}
```

Could you please help me and my team? We aren't really a programmer of any kind (economics student) and I'm really struggling with this :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you

> 1. gather information with **surveymonkey**
> 2. import data from surveymonkey to **google sheets**
> 3. you want to **refresh data** from surveymonkey in google sheets **every 5 minutes**

Well true, you should use `triggers` for that.

---

1. first of all, take a look at [this surveymonkey guide](https://www.surveymonkey.com/curiosity/google-drive-and-surveymonkey-integrate/), in case you didn't do that before
2. secondly lets create/modify a `script` with the next code

Here is an example of code **for trigger test purposes**

```js
function myFunction(){
  // change id by your actual spreadsheet ID
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("id").getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var originalRange = ss.getRange("A1");
  var destinationRange = ss.getRange("A2");
  originalRange.copyTo(destinationRange);
}
```

### What it does?

- copies the cell A1 to A2, if you launch it from Apps Script you will see a work in action.

### But how to trigger it every minute or every 5 minutes?

Follow the next step by step guide:

1. In apps script click on Menu > Edit > Current project's triggers
2. New tab with Triggers will be opened, clock on blue button Add Trigger
3. In configuration block select the next parameters:

   - Choose which function to run : **myFunction**
   - Select event source : **Time-drive**
   - Select type of time based trigger : **Minutes timer**
   - Select minute interval : **Every minute**

so it looks like this
[image]

4. click on Save

From now on your cell A1 will be copied to A2 every minute, automatically

---

Knowing this trick you can put your API Connect into myFunction to import data into Google Sheet

I hope this helps you and by the way Google has wonderful service like [Google Forms](https://forms.google.com/), you can test it as well :)

---

### References:

- [Google Apps Script - Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)
- [External APIs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external)
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Google Forms](https://forms.google.com/)

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your help! I know how to schedule scripts - the problem is I don't know how to write a scrip which would run my gscheet addon. I can't official SurveyMonkey addon, as it's not available in my country.

Also I couldn't use GForms, as it doesn't allows me to dynamically tag my links (additional tracking via utms). ;)

Comment: Hi, 
If you have more question the better way is to create another Question thread with very specific question, not a general one, you will get better and concise answers ;)
As per title of this question I understand that you wanted to solve a problem with 5 minutes trigger. 
If you consider that my question has been answered please consider to accept it. :)