# How to automatically update SurveyMonkey responses on a Google Sheets Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, surveymonkey

I'm having some trouble trying to link a SurveyMonkey survey in a Google Sheets Spreadsheet. I'm using the add-on, but the thing is that it only update manually and I need it to update automatically every hour so I get all new responses in my spreadsheet. I don't have any knowledge of API or complex scripts, so I'm kind of lost here and need a well-explained answer. Can you guys help me please? :)

PS.: I know there's some paid tools that solves my issue, but I'm really hoping to find a free solution.

I tried to use SurveyMonkey add-on but it doesn't automatically update.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time trigger on Google Scheet and Survey Monkey API addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59760438/time-trigger-on-google-scheet-and-survey-monkey-api-addon)

Comment: No, this answer is about setting a time trigger, but I already know how to trigger it. My difficulty is to create something to trigger hahahah

Comment: With respect... that question is NOT about setting time triggers, it is a workaround to achieve this: `you want to refresh data from surveymonkey in google sheets every 5 minutes`. The answer focuses on updating a cell in the spreadsheet that is intended to "trigger" the update from SurveyMonkey.